# condition based add tab on Product page - magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, tabs, update-handle

I want to add a tab on product view page in magento2.

That tab will only be visible if the customer belongs to a certain customer group.

Tabs are added via XML file, how can I create a custom handler in magento2 or use some condition on that.

Comment: do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs on Product Detail Page are rendered in this file

**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml**

**Override this file in your theme/module**

In this file **$detailedInfoGroup** contains the list of all tabs to be rendered. You can apply condition on this varibale to show your desired tabs.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the right path to solve this problem. Great